# Usage for EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE cookie?

Tags: cookie

Looking at the list of Magento cookies listed on the default "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode" cms page created on install I see an entry for :

```
EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE
A flag, which indicates whether caching is disabled or not.
```

Does anyone know if this cookie is indeed in use by Magento? I can find no reference to it being set or used within the Magento code base.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is yes, it is used: You can find it's use in the Mage_PageCache module.

The slightly longer answer is that the cookie won't actually do a lot in a standard Magento CE install, I presume this cookie is used by the full page cache when using Magento EE:

- It can be set during an event observer for `controller_action_predispatch`.
- I believe it's used by some third party full page cache modules. Finally I believe it can be used in conjunction with the full page caching offered by Zend Server.